# I am trying to use font awesome in navbar it's not working, my language is nodejs

Tags: html, css, node.js, font-awesome

I've tried to use font awesome to show on the navbar but it doesn't show. The method I use is
install `npm install font-awesome --save`
Then create a `style.css` file in `public/stylesheets`.
The setup file contains the code `@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');` Retrieve many forms from `node_modules`
Then I run the `style.css` file at `boilerplate.ejs.`
And then I put the font I want on `navbar.ejs.`
and show it at `homeV2.ejs`

But it doesn't work I know why. Can you help me?

this is the code

homeV2.ejs

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
```

navbar.ejs

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark " style="background-color: #0F293B;">
    <div class="container container-fluid">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand"></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/image/assets/img/first_logo.png" alt="" width="100" >
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/dharmas">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/consultations">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/consultations">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/consultations">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/consultations">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/consultations">Pages</a>
          </li>

          <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>

        </ul>
        <!-- <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <% if(!currentUser) {%>
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/login">เข้าสู่ระบบ</a>
          <% } else {%>
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/logout">ออกจากระบบ</a>
          <% } %>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

boilerplate.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ศูนย์ดำรงธรรม</title>
    
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/appConsultation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/appDharma.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        
    </head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <%- include('../partials/navbar') %>
    <main class="container mt-5">
        <%- include('../partials/flash') %>
        <%- body %>
    </main>
    <%- include('../partials/footer') %>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

    <script src="/javascripts/validateForms.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

app.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const ExpressError = require('./utils/ExpressError');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const User = require('./models/user');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const moment = require('moment');

const config = require('config');

const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');

const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const campgroundRoutes = require('./routes/campgrounds');
const reviewRoutes = require('./routes/reviews');
const dharmaRoutes = require('./routes/dharmas');
const reviewofdharmaRoutes = require('./routes/reviewofdharmas');
const consultationRoutes = require('./routes/consultations');
const reviewofconsultationRoutes = require('./routes/reviewofconsultations');
const articleRouter = require('./routes/articles');
const article = require('./models/article');
const dbConfig = config.get('DHARMA.dbConfig.dbName');


const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URL

mongoose.connect(dbConfig, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    // useFindAndModify: false
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
})

const app = express();

app.locals.moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('th');

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(mongoSanitize({
    replaceWith: '_'
  }))

const secret = process.env.SECRET || 'thisshouldbeabettersecret!';

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    adapter: 'connect-mongo',
    url: dbConfig,
    secret,
    touchAfter: 24 * 60 * 60
});

store.on("error", function (e) {
    console.log("SESSION STORE ERROR", e)
})

const sessionConfig = {
    store,
    name: 'session',
    secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        // secure: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}
 
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(flash());
// app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(false))


const scriptSrcUrls = [
    "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/",
    "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://kit.fontawesome.com/",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net",
];
const styleSrcUrls = [
    "https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/",
    "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/",
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/",
    "https://use.fontawesome.com/",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/",
];

const connectSrcUrls = [
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://b.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://events.mapbox.com/",
];
const fontSrcUrls = [];
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: [],
            connectSrc: ["'self'", ...connectSrcUrls],
            scriptSrc: ["'unsafe-inline'", "'self'", ...scriptSrcUrls],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", ...styleSrcUrls],
            workerSrc: ["'self'", "blob:"],
            objectSrc: [],
            imgSrc: [
                "'self'",
                "blob:",
                "data:",
                "https://res.cloudinary.com/ditv5cx1f/", //SHOULD MATCH YOUR CLOUDINARY ACCOUNT! 
                "https://images.unsplash.com/",
            ],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", ...fontSrcUrls],
        },
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.infoDharma = req.flash('infoDharma');
    res.locals.infoConsultation = req.flash('infoConsultation')
    next();
})

// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/campgrounds', campgroundRoutes)
app.use('/campgrounds/:id/reviews', reviewRoutes)
app.use('/consultations', consultationRoutes)
app.use('/consultations/:id/reviews', reviewofconsultationRoutes)
app.use('/articles', articleRouter)
app.use('/', dharmaRoutes)
app.use('/:id/reviews', reviewofdharmaRoutes)

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ExpressError('Page Not Found', 404))
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500 } = err;
    if (!err.message) err.message = 'Oh No, Something Went Wrong!'
    res.status(statusCode).render('error', { err })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serving on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Which version of Font Awesome are you using?

Comment: I use "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"

Comment: You need to verify the icons used. For instance `<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>` should be `<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. You can check https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/search

Comment: Probably your are not done yet, as your `<i>` is not wrapped in an `<li><a…`. Please remember also to provide an accessible name for that menu option, which probably is search? `<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" aria-label="Search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>`